# Make settings for an application to be changed by admin only in a .Net application?

Tags: c#-2.0

I created a .Net application with some app settings. I want to make these app settings to be changed only by an administrator. Any help is grateful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Go to windows explorer. Right click on the configuration file, go to security tab. Remove write rights from everyone that is not the administrator.

Comment: Is there any other way of setting it in the .Net application?